# How to use "+" character in query parameters with werkzeug 2.3.0?

Tags: python, werkzeug

Since the update from werkzeug 2.2.3 to 2.3.0, the encoding was changed.
As a result, a request that had a query parameter with a value containing the character "+" is now changed, with every "+" replaced with a whitespace.

We have tried url encoding the "+" (replacing it with a %2B), but it seems like it only works on the part of the url before the "?", so not on query parameters.

As a temporary fix, we pinned the werkzeug version.
However, this is not the solution we are looking for. We would like a way to have "+" in a query parameter value with the new werkzeug version.

Comment: There is a github issue tracking this problem:  https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2657.  Until it is resolved, staying on the prior version seems to be the best workaround.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Thank you for your answer. I somehow missed this issue when looking at recent issues a few hours ago.